# How do you masquerade a hard drive partition as a removable disk?

Tags: windows, partitioning, multi-boot, google-chrome-os, boot-partition

I am trying to install [Chromium OS](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/) on my Windows computer as a secondary OS. I have already used Chrome OS on a live USB before by using [Win32DiskImager](https://launchpad.net/win32-image-writer/+download) which writes an image to a removable device.

However, now I want to install it on a bootable partition, but Win32DiskImager doesn't accept writing to a non-removable disk. How do you have a hard drive partition masquerade as a removable disk so that Win32DiskImager can write to it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you don't – except maybe by writing a Windows device driver that does this, if drivers can do this...

Using a different image writer, such as [`dd`](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd), will be *much* easier than performing this kind of brain surgery.

```
dd if=myimage.iso of=\\.\e:
```